# Google Translation .Net API support for Proxy settings

Tags: .net, .net-core, grpc, google-translate, google-translation-api

I am trying to access google translator services using nuget package of GoogleTranslator V3. In our production we have a server with proxy enabled hence we need to invoke the Google translator V3 API's using proxy settings.

Any one has ever done that or know how to pass proxy server settings [url/port/username/password].

Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: Is [this](https://developers.google.com/gdata/articles/proxy_setup#dotnet) useful for the purpose?

Comment: This is for Version 2 where we have WebProxy which can embedded but how to do it in Version 3 where they are using GRPC instead of simple Webrequest.